# Get any Json value with react.js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to create a website and that website include a few dynamic graph with [Plotly](https://plot.ly) but sometimes server can down and people can see the 404 error which is annoying.

One of the solution that I am thinking save all graph as image and if server down serve up the image files while server down otherwise show the graphs again.

I have a JSON file and I store the link of the graphs in the JSON file and everything is Ok.

I want to create one more line in JSON for each image (`plotly_img_path`) path like this

```
 },
                "Annual": {
                    "Title": "Annual Change By Dimension",
                    "Description": "This is description,
                    "Min value": "0",
                    "Max value": "0",
                    "Rationale": " ",
                    "No. of values": "",
                    "plotly_file_path": "https://plot.ly/xxxxx/1237"
                    "plotly_img_path": "../images/Graph-Img/1237.jpeg"

                }
```

dynamic graph is working and if I put my image path manually like this:

```
<img src={require("../images/Graph-Img/1237.jpeg")}></img>
```

it is working as well but my problem is I need to get the with Json path

```
Data['Dimensional']['Index']['Graphs']['Annual']['plotly_img_path'];
```

when I check with `Console.log()` I can see img path above but I am getting

×
Error: Cannot find module "."

Sorry if it is confusing. Basically; I need to take the path in Json file and serve in image in that file path.

**Update:** As I mentioned my error is Cannot find module "." and this from "Webpack missing module error"! when you put path in `<img src={require("../images/Graph-Img/1237.jpeg")}></img>` I can see the image but when I put Json keys to in I have the error(If I do not use "require" I can see only empty frame).

Comment: Try import image `import img1237 from "../images/Graph-Img/1237.jpeg"` and assign it to `src` props. And add some minimal example in codesandbox to it, your code seems ok.

Comment: Why is your server going down so often? How can you serve up an image if your server is down? Sounds like it's still up - in that case serve a cached response if the issue is further downstream? Or better yet fix the issue that's causing it to go down.

Comment: Why `<img src={annual.plotly_file_path}></img>` is not working?

Comment: @DennisVash I have 120 graphs so I was thinking abut different way. @Dominic I am using `Axios` checking the Httpserver status for my graph provider not my website server.